# Will removing Open JDK stablize crashing ubuntu?

Tags: 13.04, java, eclipse, jdk

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 on an asus zenbook.

Mostly this performs very well and I'm quite happy with it but when using Eclipse 3.8 I'm having problems which sometimes crash my whole system. This is becoming quite frustrating.

Occasionally Ubuntu recovers the crash and sends a bug report, listing Open JDK as the culprit.

Has anyone else experienced this? Will Removing Open JDK and putting proper Oracle / Java on my machine help?
Is this a difficult operation?

Many Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383992/why-does-my-eclipse-indigo-crash-on-ubuntu-13-04-with-oracle-jdk-64bit), which is to just add the line

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

to your eclispse.ini

The eclipse.ini can be found at

```
usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse.ini
```

Also the bug report is [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404776)